# Session lost after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session-variables

On my website

1. Filling form before login save data in Session
2. Login Using Linkedin ID
3. after login at Pageload taking data from session then inserting into SQL data base

My problem is some times I am getting session and other times I am not getting session (Session Lost) ( mostly when 3-4 people testing at the same time... 2-3 get session and 1-2 not getting session)

Can any one tell me what is the problem? How can I solve this problem?

Any another way to do this task?

Stroing in session before login 
                Session["sesObjFundRaiseSeek"] = objFundRaiseSeek;

Getting after login

```
if (Session["sesObjSellSeekBL"] != null)
 {
   clsSellSeekBL ObjSellSeekBL = (clsSellSeekBL)Session["sesObjSellSeekBL"];  
 }
```

Comment: Any code you can present? Please be more specific!

Comment: We really can't help you if you don't show us your code.

Comment: Difficult to answer with the little information provided, do you reset the session variable anywhere or set it to null? Maybe you instantiate the object somewhere that you put in session? Sounds to me like you are setting the session value more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a problem with your sessions timing out after a very short period of time? You can input the default session timeout within the web.config. This is done right under system.web. Here is an example where 480 is the number of minutes:

```
<sessionState timeout="480"></sessionState>
```

For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx

An alternate solution is to use Cookies. I would recommend using Cookies to store user state information. Since Cookies are stored on the users computer, it is easier to configure:

I set to expiration date to 100000 days later in the example below:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("sesObjSellSeekBL");
myCookie.Value = Convert.ToString(user_id); //store the user id here at the very least
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100000d);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

Here is how you check your Cookie:

```
if (Request.Cookies["sesObjSellSeekBL"] != null)
```

Here is how you log the user out:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("sesObjSellSeekBL");
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? Have you configured the Idle Timeout-out property?

Comment: IIS 6.0 and I did not configured the Idle Timeout-out property?

Comment: Here is some information on the idle timeout property for IIS 6. http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b39a8ab9-7331-4bad-a89a-0210aadbd4a7.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: On a side note, I would recommend using Cookies to store user state information. Since Cookies are stored on the users computer, you do not have to configure anything in IIS.

Comment: any one can tell me any other solution ?

Comment: I want to understand ...main problem

Comment: I have an included in my answer an example of how to use Cookies.

Comment: Hi user2535489,  Thanks for code .....But if client cookie is disable then what we can do ...? nothing ...that's why I don't want to use cookie ...

Comment: Let's try configuring the Idle Timeout property in IIS. Let's see if it solves the problem.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325056   Now I am not able to find any solution .....